# Testing 10.000 VU in JMeter in 10 seconds

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I need to test 200.000 VU hitting an app in 10 seconds, so I started to make a test of 10.000 VU, running Jmeter in Non-GUI mode, to see the response of my computer, my internet connection and the site response, but I got 83.50% of Errors.

95% of the errors were these:

> Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException/Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect

This means that the internet connection was not enough for the short time of the test?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Running 200K users**

Generally speaking in traditional HTTP running 200.000 users from one machine is impossible: there isn't that many ports. I.e. if you maximize your port usage (and it's likely you need to change OS settings to do that, since usually OS will limit number of open ports to somehwere between 1000 and 10000), JMeter will have about 64500 ports to run requests on. Each JMeter HTTP sampler needs a separate port, so you need 200K ports. Thus you need to have at least 4 machines to run 200K requests concurrently.

But that may not be enough: if you have more than one request sequentially (like most performance tests do), you will be able to run even less concurrent requests, since ports are usually not closed right away after request is done, so next request has to use a different port.

Don't forget that server *also* must be able to receive similar load.

But even that may not be enough: JMeter needs to have enough memory to accommodate 10-30K threads. Size of thread in memory will depend on a few things, and how your script is designed among them.

Bottom line: with all the tweaking, realistically, port availability limits number of concurrent requests JMeter can run from one machine to 10-30K concurrent users. Thus to test 200K users, you need about 7-20 JMeter machines.

**Running 10K users**

If you were testing in a designated environment (where clients and servers are next to each other with optimized network between them), you should be able to run 10K users from one machine, if other limits, e.g. memory and max ports were properly tweaked. But sounds like you are trying to test them over the internet connection?

Well, 2 problems here:

- Performance testing over internet connection is absolutely pointless. You don't know what is between you and servers, and how those things in between are changing the shape of the load. You won't know if it was 10K concurrent requests, or 10K sequential requests. And results will only tell you how fast your internet is.
- Any ISP will have a limit on number of connections from one IP, and it will be well below 10K. Not to mention that some ISPs may flag / temporary ban your IP for such flood.

Bottom line: whoever asked you to test 10K or 200K concurrent users, should also provide a set of JMeter machines to run this test from. Those machines should be *close to* tested servers, preferably without any extra routing in between (or with well known and well configured routing)

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detail answer. Yes, I'm trying to test them over the internet connection. I found that AWS has some on demand machines that are use for testing 100.000 concurrents users, but I don't know if that is true.

Comment: If I do it locally my server doesn't have the same features that the server where is going to be the app, how do you do in those scenarios?

Comment: @AnaGallardo: perf testing on AWS is possible, but afaik quite expensive. What you could do is to test on local server to make sure you don't have any obvious problems, and them move to AWS. Ideally, however, you replicate locally the server you will have in prod.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that stressing your application by kicking off 200k users at once is a good idea (same applies to 10k users) as the results, even in case of success, won't tell the full story. Moreover, in case of error you will be able to state only that 10k users in 10 seconds is not possible, however you won't have the information like:

- What was the number of users when errors start occurring
- What is the correlation between number of concurrent users and response time and/or [throughput](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2011/07/05/performance-testing-what-is-throughput/)
- What is the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) (the maximum system performance)

So I would recommend re-running your test and increasing the load **gradually** from one virtual user to 10 000 and see when it breaks. The breaking point is called [bottleneck](http://www.agileload.com/agileload/blog/2012/11/27/web-applications-performance-symptoms-and-bottlenecks-identification) and the cause can be determined like:

1. First of all make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as default JMeter configuration is not suitable for high loads and if JMeter is not capable of sending requests fast enough you will not get accurate results. Most probably you will have to [run JMeter in Distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter), it is highly unlikely you will be able to mimic 20k requests per second from a single machine (or it has to be a very powerful one)
2. Set up monitoring of the application under test in order to ensure that it has enough headroom in terms of CPU, RAM, Disk, etc. You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this
3. Check your application infrastructure, like JMeter the majority of middleware components like web/application servers, load balancers, databases, etc. default configurations are suitable for development and debugging, they need to be tuned for high throughput.
4. Check your application code using [profiler tools telemetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)), the reason could be in i.e. slow DB query, inefficient algorithm, large object, heavy function, etc.